# Combobox store after render

Tags: javascript, extjs, ext3

I have a form that gets populated with the results after rowchange event.
I have a  modified combobox ( superboxselect).

I would need to have its values selected and listed after row click with values for that row.

The data is in the store for FormPanel  as one field( identifiers - array).

I can set active values with:

```
field.setValue(record.get('identifiers'));
```

But i would need to create store and assign in to the combobox first.

Normally you could use:

```
store: ['Red', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Brown', 'Blue', 'Pink', 'Black']
```

if its a simple array. But how to do that outside the combobox config and set it later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      field.store.loadData(record.get('identifiers'));
      field.setValue(record.get('identifiers'));
```

With

```
    store: ['No identifiers']
```

in the config for the combo  seems to do the trick.